# Checking if a string contains more than just keywords C++

Tags: c++, string, format, indexof

Thank you for clicking on my question.

After countless hours of searching, I have not come across a solution and its quite difficult to search for something you don't know how to properly phrase in a search. Please help me out, I would appreciate it.

The data of the string would be like:

```
std::string keyword 1 "Hello";
std::string keyword 2 "Ola";
std::string test = Keyword1+Keyword2+keyword2;
```

Example of what I'm trying to achieve as a pseudocode:

```
if(test.contains(more then the 2 keywords))
```

I wanna make sure the string has other text than just the keywords above.

Comment: Do not tag `C`.  Your code is C++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove all instances of these keywords from your data and see what's left. It's not terribly efficient but shouldn't matter for reasonably sized inputs.

```
bool contains_more_than(std::vector<std::string> const& keywords, std::string sample) {
  for (std::string const& keyword: keywords) {
    size_t pos;
    while ((pos = sample.find(keyword)) != sample.npos) {
      sample.replace(pos, keyword.size(), "");
    }
  }
  return !sample.empty();
}
```

Note that this might fail if some keyword is a substring of another:

`contains_more_than({"123", "12345"}, "12345")` returns True.

To avoid this you can first sort your keywords by `std::string::size`:

```
std::string(keywords.begin(), keywords.end(), 
    [](std::string const& s1, std::string const& s2) { 
        return s1.size() > s2.size(); 
    });
```

Now:

`contains_more_than({"12345", "123"}, "12345")` returns False

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution: expressed as a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), you are testing whether the string matches `^(Hello|Ola)*$`. That is, does the whole string match any number of repeats of "Hello" and/or "Ola" (and with nothing else)? You can use the [regex standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) to match regular expressions in C++.